# Woocommerce hook not triggering emails for custom statuses

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation

I've registered custom order statuses in a plugin I'm working on, but I can't get emails to fire when moving in or out of one of these statuses. (including to/from a core status, ie. the processing/completed emails don't fire when moving from a custom status).

I've registered every possible combination of actions I can think of (excluding on-hold and pending, based on our use case)

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing please?

Initial class:

```
<?php
/**
 * @author BAKKBONE Australia
 * @package Bkf_WC_Email
 * @license GNU General Public License (GPL) 3.0
**/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    return;
}

/**
 * Class Bkf_WC_Email
 */
class Bkf_WC_Email {

    /**
     * Bkf_WC_Email constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_email_classes', array( $this, 'bkf_register_email' ), 90, 1 );
        define( 'CUSTOM_WC_EMAIL_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
        add_filter('woocommerce_email_actions', array($this, 'bkf_woocommerce_email_actions'), 10, 1);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $emails
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function bkf_register_email( $emails ) {
        $emails['WC_Email_Customer_Scheduled_Order'] = include __DIR__ . 'emails/class-wc-customer-scheduled-order.php';
        $emails['WC_Email_Customer_Prepared_Order'] = include __DIR__ . 'emails/class-wc-customer-made-order.php';
        $emails['WC_Email_Customer_Out_for_Delivery_Order'] = include __DIR__ . 'emails/class-wc-customer-out-order.php';

        return $emails;
    }

    public function bkf_woocommerce_email_actions($actions)
    {
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_scheduled';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_made';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_out';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_relay';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_processing';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_completed';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_scheduled_to_made';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_scheduled_to_out';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_scheduled_to_relay';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_scheduled_to_processing';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_scheduled_to_completed';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_made_to_scheduled';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_made_to_out';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_made_to_relay';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_made_to_processing';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_made_to_completed';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_out_to_scheduled';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_out_to_made';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_out_to_relay';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_out_to_processing';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_out_to_completed';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_relay_to_scheduled';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_relay_to_made';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_relay_to_out';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_relay_to_processing';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_relay_to_completed';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_scheduled';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_made';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_out';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_relay';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_completed';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_to_scheduled';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_to_made';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_to_out';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_to_relay';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_to_processing';
        $bkfoptions = get_option("bkf_options_setting");
        if($bkfoptions["bkf_petals"] == "1") {
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_new';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_accept';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_reject';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_scheduled_to_new';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_scheduled_to_accept';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_scheduled_to_reject';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_made_to_new';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_made_to_accept';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_made_to_reject';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_out_to_new';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_out_to_accept';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_out_to_reject';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_relay_to_new';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_relay_to_accept';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_relay_to_reject';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_new';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_accept';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_reject';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_to_new';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_to_accept';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_to_reject';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_new_to_scheduled';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_new_to_made';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_new_to_out';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_new_to_relay';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_new_to_processing';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_new_to_completed';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_new_to_accept';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_new_to_reject';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_accept_to_scheduled';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_accept_to_made';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_accept_to_out';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_accept_to_relay';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_accept_to_processing';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_accept_to_completed';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_accept_to_new';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_accept_to_reject';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_reject_to_scheduled';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_reject_to_made';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_reject_to_out';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_reject_to_relay';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_reject_to_processing';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_reject_to_completed';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_reject_to_new';
$actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_reject_to_accept';
        }
        return $actions;
    }
  
}

new Bkf_WC_Email();
```

Specific email's class:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Email' ) ) {
    return;
}

/**
 * Class WC_Email_Customer_Out_for_Delivery_Order
 */
class WC_Email_Customer_Out_for_Delivery_Order extends WC_Email {

    /**
     * Create an instance of the class.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    function __construct() {

        $this->id          = 'customer_out_order';
        $this->title       = __( 'Order Out for Delivery', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->description = __( 'An email sent to the customer when an order is out for delivery.', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->customer_email = true;
        $this->heading     = __( 'Order Out for Delivery', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->subject     = sprintf( _x( '[%s] Order Out for Delivery', 'default email subject for out for delivery emails', 'woocommerce' ), '{blogname}' );

        $this->template_html  = 'emails/customer-out-order.php';
        $this->template_plain = 'emails/plain/customer-out-order.php';
        $this->template_base  = CUSTOM_WC_EMAIL_PATH . 'templates/';

        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_out', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Trigger Function that will send this email to the customer.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    function trigger( $order_id ) {
        $this->object = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        if ( version_compare( '3.0.0', WC()->version, '>' ) ) {
            $order_email = $this->object->billing_email;
        } else {
            $order_email = $this->object->get_billing_email();
        }

        $this->recipient = $order_email;


        if ( ! $this->is_enabled() || ! $this->get_recipient() ) {
            return;
        }

        $this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
    }

    /**
     * Get content html.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_html() {
        return wc_get_template_html( $this->template_html, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading(),
            'additional_content' => $this->get_additional_content(),
            'sent_to_admin' => false,
            'plain_text'    => false,
            'email'         => $this
        ), '', $this->template_base );
    }

    /**
     * Get content plain.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_plain() {
        return wc_get_template_html( $this->template_plain, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading(),
            'additional_content' => $this->get_additional_content(),
            'sent_to_admin' => false,
            'plain_text'    => true,
            'email'         => $this
        ), '', $this->template_base );
    }

}

return new WC_Email_Customer_Out_for_Delivery_Order();
```

I welcome any ideas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the triggers. Try to hook into `woocommerce_order_status_changed` action and fire your e-mails as you wish based on `$from` and `$to` statuses.

Here's a preview with 3 examples:

```
function custom_woocommerce_order_status_changed( $order_id, $from, $to, $order ) {

    // Get all WC mailer emails
    $wc_emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

    // Example A: Handle (from) 'my-custom-status' triggers
    if( $from == 'my-custom-status' ) {

        // Trigger 'completed' e-mail if changing to 'completed'
        if( $to == 'completed' ) {
            $wc_emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
        }
    }

    // Example B: Handle (from) 'processing' triggers
    if( $from == 'processing' ) {

        // Trigger 'my-custom-status' e-mail if changing to 'my-custom-status'
        if( $to == 'my-custom-status' ) {
            $wc_emails['WC_Email_Customer_My_Custom_Status_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
        }
    }

    // Example C: Handle (to) 'my-custom-status' triggers
    // This will fire the email for every order changed to this status (whatever the $from status is)
    if( $to == 'my-custom-status' ) {
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Customer_My_Custom_Status_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'custom_woocommerce_order_status_changed', 20, 4 );
```

**Note:** Try to write these conditions as simply and straightforward as you can. Remember that if your order change scenario will be a duplicate, the e-mail will be also triggered (sent) multiple times.

Comment: Thanks!! We have liftoff - sort of. [Here's what I arrived at code-wise](https://github.com/bakkbone/bakkbone-florist-companion/blob/main/trunk/incl/emails/status-email.php) - but it's sending the emails twice now, funnily enough

Comment: @Scott-BAKKBONEAustralia Yes, it is. Check the **note** in my answer, it is exactly what happened. You set multiple triggers based on `$to` order statuses (e.g. when order status changes to `processing`, `completed`), but WooCommerce already have these triggers in it's core. **You only need to define the triggers that are not already part of the core**. In your case, keep the `$to` custom based triggers (scheduled, made, out) as you have, but wrap your `$to` (processing, completed) triggers to another condition - `$from` has to be one of your custom statuses.

Comment: Will give that a go, but that doesn't explain the custom status ones firing twice as well...?

Comment: Do you still have `bkf_woocommerce_email_actions` callback function somewhere in the plugin? Maybe try disabling that one for a test.

Comment: Just got rid of that, everything still firing twice even with the $to's wrapped for processing etc

Comment: Could you share the whole plugin code? I would double check if there aren't other `trigger()` calls for your e-mails - somehow those e-mails are getting triggered twice. This should be easy to debug (e.g. using XDebug), but it's hard to do without the access to the dev environment.

Comment: I just noticed you already shared whole repo. You are indeed calling the `trigger()` function twice. E.g. inside your `class-wc-customer-out-order.php` class you are calling the `trigger` method on **line 34**. Same goes probably for other classes as well.

Comment: Oops, I failed to update the git when we took that call out of the test site - have updated the repo now - outcome hasn't changed unfortunately

Comment: Ahhhhhh, it was because i was returning a new Bkf_WC_Email at the bottom of status-email.php - thanks so much for your help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forgot to add "_notification" suffix to your email action hook call, so in your case:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_out_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
```

For anybody else trying to figure out what all needs to be set up for the action hooks only, I'll try to summ up here what I found today:

Class `WC_Emails` actually contains own set of action hooks (see `WC_Emails::init_transactional_emails()`) for which it is allowed to send "notifications".

If you want to send email using your own custom action hook you defined somewhere before in the Wordpress, you need to first add it to `WC_Emails` registered hooks using the `woocommerce_email_actions` filter.

```
function add_custom_hook_actions ($email_actions) {
    $email_actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_your-own-status';
    $email_actions[] = 'another_random_action_hook';
    return $email_actions;
};
add_filter('woocommerce_email_actions', 'add_custom_hook_actions');
```

These `WC_Emails` registered action hooks then can be used in your `WC_Email` extending template class, calling defined `WC_Email` registered hook with "_notification" suffix.

```
class WC_Email_Awesome_Custom_Template extends WC_Email
{

    /**
     * Class constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // ... some code to define email template

        // Triggers for this email.
        add_action(
            'woocommerce_order_status_your-own-status_notification', 
            array($this, 'trigger'),
            10,
            1
        );
        add_action(
            'another_random_action_hook_notification', 
            array($this, 'trigger'),
            10,
            1
        );
        
        // ... rest of the constructor
    }

    // ... rest of the class
}
```

Or you can call it using the mailer directly wherever needed, similarly to the way already described here by others.

```
WC()->mailer()->emails['WC_Email_Awesome_Custom_Template']->trigger($order->get_id(), $order, true);
```

Hopefully it saves someone time.

Comment: I had to use also ''woocommerce_email_classes'' hook to add my new mail to make it work